# Add new HTML structure to <img/> on post entry, if there is more than one <img/>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transformation, blogspot

### Question: What codes should I paste on my blog HEAD?

Using any method (jQuery, javaScript, CSS, HTML, exclude php),  how to add new HTML structure to `<img/>` on post entry, if there is more than one `<img/>` ?

Blog platfrom: [Blogger.com](http://ideone.com/mmang)

### Example of entry content

If there is only one `<img/>` the post entry. No additions or changes in the structure of HTML.

*But if there is more than one `<img/>` (example below),*

```
<div class="summary post-body entry-content">

<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RiUUAdlHMSE/TehdEWtMyCI/AAAAAAAAASA/AXMQng9etR8/s1600/nemo.jpg"/>
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mUIbhIqAyw4/Tehc-zbmK_I/AAAAAAAAAR8/MlPQb_D5P_A/s1600/walle.jpg"/>
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BRh1P_3XyDo/Tehc9UlYh0I/AAAAAAAAAR4/6TKLJs25ecg/s1600/up.jpg"/>
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R_jrCzUDe-g/TehdHXDrK8I/AAAAAAAAASE/fW_-YGhHx20/s1600/toystory.jpg"/>

 <!-- end summary post-body entry-content --></div>
```

***How to transform it as HTML below (automaticly),***

```
<div class="summary post-body entry-content">

               <!-- start te-container --><div class="te-container">

        <div class="te-controls">
        <select id="type">
        <option value="te-flip1">Flip 1</option>
        <option value="te-flip2">Flip 2</option>
        <option value="te-flip3">Flip 3</option>
        <option value="te-flip4">Flip 4</option>
        </select>
        <a id="te-next" href="#" class="te-next">next</a>
                             <div class="te-shadow"></div>
        </div>
                    <!-- start-wrapper --><div id="te-wrapper" class="te-wrapper">

     <div class="te-images">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RiUUAdlHMSE/TehdEWtMyCI/AAAAAAAAASA/AXMQng9etR8/s1600/nemo.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-mUIbhIqAyw4/Tehc-zbmK_I/AAAAAAAAAR8/MlPQb_D5P_A/s1600/walle.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-BRh1P_3XyDo/Tehc9UlYh0I/AAAAAAAAAR4/6TKLJs25ecg/s1600/up.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-R_jrCzUDe-g/TehdHXDrK8I/AAAAAAAAASE/fW_-YGhHx20/s1600/toystory.jpg"/>
     </div>
                                    <div class="te-cover">
    <!-- HOW TO DO AUTOMATICLY, FISRT <img/> located at here --><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-RiUUAdlHMSE/TehdEWtMyCI/AAAAAAAAASA/AXMQng9etR8/s1600/nemo.jpg"/>
                                                    </div>
    <div class="te-transition">
    <div class="te-card">
      <div class="te-front"></div>
      <div class="te-back"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

                  <!-- end te-wrapper --></div>
                  <!-- end te-container --></div>

<!-- end summary post-body entry-content --></div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do? what about adding fiddle of your effort?

Comment: @DeepakManwal -- I try to transfrom it (if there is more than one <img/>), to automatically build manual images slider, like this--> http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageTransitions/

Comment: do you want to load the first image from <div id="te-images"> in  <div class="te-cover"> ? Is that what you want?

Comment: @codeSpy: i want all of `div`, `class`, `select`, and `option` appear too like as example above along with `img`. Including load the first image from `<div class="te-cover"> <!-- load here --> </div>`. -- if there is more than one `<img/>` on my post entry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a way to solve your problem,

First to be clear as you wanted to add certain markup directly inside your code, I put those inside a variable. Kept the child node in another variable, appended that with existing markup and updated certain elements as asked for.And I would surely ask for a better solution if available.

Here's the script for your scenario,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//checks if no. of image is > 1
if($(".summary").children().length > 1){

   // gets all elements inside that div
   var images = $(".summary").children();

   //makes that div empty 
   $(".summary").empty();

   //kept whole markup inside a variable
   var newLayout = "<div class='te-container'> <div class='te-controls'><select id='type'><option value='te-flip1'>Flip 1</option><option value='te-flip2'>Flip 2</option><option value='te-flip3'>Flip 3</option><option value='te-flip4'>Flip 4</option></select><a id='te-next' href='#' class='te-next'>next</a><div class='te-shadow'></div></div><div id='te-wrapper' class='te-wrapper'><div class='te-images'></div><div class='te-cover'></div><div class='te-transition'><div class='te-card'><div class='te-front'></div><div class='te-back'></div></div></div></div></div>";

    //appends the layout inside .summary div
    $(".summary").append(newLayout);

    //adds the images inside new div
    $(images).clone().appendTo(".te-images");

    //gets first child image of .te-images
    var firstImagePath = $(".te-images img:first-child").attr("src"); 

    //adds first child image of .te-images inside .te-cover div 
    $(".te-cover").append("<img src="+ firstImagePath + " />");

}
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/cwC6W/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about "automaticly" you meant.

But if u want that `div` "automaticly" appear `img`, you can use js. Named the `div` which contain `img`. Then wirte this in js :

```
$(document).ready( function () {
   document.getElementsByName('div_name_here').innerHTML = <img src='...'/>
}
```

Hope that help. Sorry my English is not good.

Comment: Thnkas @ntlam: But how include all of `div`, `class`, `select`, and `option` appear too like as example above along with `img`. Including load the first image from `<div class="te-cover"> <!-- load here --> </div>`. -- if there is more than one `<img/>` on my post entry